# EC2 instance to assume an IAM role so that I don't have to enter token everytime to use services on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs

On my client's AWS account, security credentials are generated everytime we login to their AWS sandbox account. This credentials file is automatically generated and downloaded via a Chrome plugin(SAML to AWS STS Key Conversion).
We then have to place the generated content to the `./aws/credentials` file inside an EC2 instance in the same AWS account. This is little inconvenient as we have to update the generated credentials and session_token into the credentials file inside the EC2 instance every time we launch a Terraform script.

Is there any way we can attach any role so that we can just use the EC2 instance without entering the credentials into the credentials file.
Please suggest.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "use the EC2 instance"?

Comment: Hi @DusanBajic, I have an EC2 instance in the same client sandbox environment where we login with the console "connect" mode from the AWS dashboard which gives a web access to EC2 console. I have run Terraform scripts from this EC2 instance, but since the security keys changes everytime we login to AWS console, we have to enter this into the credentials file to use Terraform. Hope this is clear now.

Comment: I see, but you answered your question in your title, https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/assign-iam-role-ec2-instance/ (also check "Related Information" articles)

Comment: I am confused on this actually. what role should give an EC2 instance the ability to run a terraform command without me having to put the credentials in the credentials file.

Comment: You create a role and you assign permissions to that role (permissions should depend on which AWS resources you are trying to usewith terraform). When you assign that role to the instance, then terraform (or any other role-aware app which is running from that instance) can utilize those permissions, without requiring any additional credentials. https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/index.html#ec2-role

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Work out what a reasonable, minimal set of permissions the Terraform script needs to create its AWS resources, then create an IAM role with those permissions, then add that IAM role to the instance (or launch a new instance with the role). Don't have a ~/.aws/credentials file on the instance or it will take precedence over the IAM role-based credentials.

Comment: @DusanBajic and jarmod thanks for this. I got this working on my own AWS account by attaching a role to my ec2 instance from where I execute the my Terraform scripts and this setup is working. I will have to see how this can be replicated into my client's AWS where session tokens are generated everytime we login to the AWS console.

Comment: When you log into the AWS console, you are assuming a role that is associated with your federated login. For you to be able to launch an EC2 instance with the Terraform role, your login role will need permission to pass the Terraform role to EC2. See PassRole in the IAM documentation.